# How to ensure function with promise continues execution

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have a function in a react-native application that is executed on a button press, it calls an async action, and then resets the navigation stack. the function looks something like this:

```
confirm = () => {
  this.props.addEvent(args);
  this.props.loading != true ? this.props.navigation.dispatch(popAction) : null; 
}
```

the addEvent() action looks like this:

```
export const addEvent = (event, msgId, convoId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.UPDATING });
        console.log('Firestore Write: (actions/agenda) => addEvent()');

        return firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('events')
            .add({
                date: event.date,
                token: event.token,
                withName: event.sender
            })
            .then((success) => {
                updateReqToScheduled(msgId, { uid: event.schedulerId, convoId: convoId });
                dispatch({ type: types.EVENT_ADD_SUCCESS });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('ERROR => addEvent()' + '\n' + err.message);
                dispatch({ type: types.EVENT_ADD_FAIL, info: err.message });
            });
    };
};
```

the pre-firebase log statement executes, the document is added, and the `updateReqToScheduled` function execution begins. it looks like:

```
const updateReqToScheduled = (id, reader) => {
    console.log('Firestore Write: (actions/agenda) => updateReqToScheduled()');
    return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('messages')
        .doc(id)
        .update({ read: true })
        .then((success) => {
            return updateConvoUnread(reader);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
};
```

this function also executes completely. the `updateConvoUnread()` function looks like:

```
const updateConvoUnread = (reader) => {
    console.log('Firestore Read: (actions/agenda) => updateConvoUnread( 1 )');
    return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('messages')
        .where('userConvos', 'array-contains', reader.convoId)
        .where('sender', '!=', reader.uid)
        .where('read', '==', false)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            console.log('PRECONDITION');
            if (querySnapshot.empty == true) {
                console.log('Firestore Write: (actions/agenda) => updateConvoUnread( 2 )');

                return firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('user-conversations')
                    .doc(reader.convoId)
                    .update({ unread: false });
            } else {
                console.log('ELSE CLAUSE');
                //return;
            }
            console.log('POST - IF');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('ERROR => updateConvoUnread(): ' + err.message);
        });
};
```

the very first pre-firebase log statement executes, but no other log statement executes, not in the `then()`, not in the `catch()` and not in the conditional statement, thus the function execution halts and the navigation stack reset isn't executed.

Can anyone advise on the situation?

Comment: You don't see any of the console.logs? Neither in the catch, nor in the then?

Comment: Is the function returning only firebase because of the newline character?  Try putting the whole return in parenthesis? `( )`

Answer (score 1):

Use async on your function declarations and await on the firebase calls

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with the firebase query. a name of the field was incorrect. it halted everything. once corrected the function finished as expected and the route was reset.